# Unable to trace syscall via ftrace

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls, ftrace

I'm using ftrace to get trace for sys_read call in kernel. With function or graph tracers, setting set_ftrace_filter to sys_write fails

```
# echo sys_read > tracing/set_ftrace_filter                                                                                                                                            
-sh: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

Here are my ftrace kconfigs

```
# zcat /proc/config.gz | grep -i ftrace
CONFIG_HAVE_DYNAMIC_FTRACE=y
CONFIG_HAVE_FTRACE_MCOUNT_RECORD=y
CONFIG_FTRACE=y
CONFIG_FTRACE_SYSCALLS=y
CONFIG_DYNAMIC_FTRACE=y
CONFIG_FTRACE_MCOUNT_RECORD=y
# CONFIG_FTRACE_STARTUP_TEST is not set
```

I do not have sys_read or sys_write in available_filter_functions as well. I'm using 3.14 kernel on an arm platform. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't figured already

```
# egrep -i "^sys_read$|^sys_write$" tracing/available_filter_functions
SyS_read
SyS_write
```

Comment: Yep, figured this out. Also sys_read and sys_write can be seen in trace if we enable event tracepoints for syscall entry. e.g. for sys_read

`echo 1 > tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_read/enable`